# Installable trigger onFormSubmit from non-Google form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, google-sheets

Thanks to everyone for their help in advance.

As a general novice to scripts and Installable Triggers specifically, I have searched all over for the technique of how to do this and haven't found what I need. I will try to break down what I am looking for as best I can.

1.) I am using a form service that is not through Google and I need this email script to trigger when a form is submitted via this service.

- Currently I am using a Simple Trigger that runs every 5 minutes which is super annoying because it slows down the whole project and is obviously not very efficient.

2.) I don't know where the 'Trigger' function needs to be placed within the script so I will post the simple script that I am using and hopefully you guys can direct me to where it needs to be placed (and if it even matters?).

Finally, I have already visited all of the links both through Google and Formstack on this issue and have been unable to piece together the result I am looking for. **Again, I am a novice at this trigger part so a walk-through is very much appreciated! :-)**

Thanks again!

Edit: script

```
function Email1() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3"));
    var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 18;   // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:B19
    var dataRange = (ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3')).getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 19)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
        if(row[0]!="") 
            var message = row[1];       // Second column
        var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
        var clientEmail = row[13];  // Thirteenth column
        if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
            var subject = "APPOINTMENT SCHEDULED";
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {noReply:true, cc:clientEmail, bcc:   
                'xxxxx.myemail.com'});
            (ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3')).getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
            // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
            SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any sample code?

Comment: Hi phatskat! Thanks for reaching out. I'm not sure if this will format correctly on here or not but here is what I trying to 'trigger' once the form is submitted (added to question)

Comment: @Drew I suggested an edit to indent the code for readability.

Comment: Did you find an answer yet?

Comment: I MAY have but I haven't had time to play around with it. Could 'on-change' really be the answer? Honestly I'm not going to be able to play around with it for a week or more but if you could or do, please let me know!